# Problemas com objetos usando sockets em java

Tags: java, socket, objetos, redes

Estou tentando passar o objeto pessoa que foi instanciado no servidor para o cliente. Mas não estou conseguindo. Abaixo estão as classes que usei:

**Servidor**

```
public class ServidorTCPBasico {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(12345);
        System.out.println("Servidor ouvindo a porta 12345");
        while (true) {

            Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("José", "Zé");

            Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
            System.out.println("Cliente conectado: " + cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            ObjectOutputStream saida = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            saida.flush();
            saida.writeObject(pessoa);
            saida.close();
            cliente.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {

    }
}}
```

**Cliente**

```
public class ClienteTCPBasico {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1",12345);
      ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
      Pessoa pessoa = (Pessoa)entrada.readObject();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Dados da pessoa:" + pessoa.toString());
      entrada.close();
      System.out.println("Conexão encerrada");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

**Classe Pessoa**

```
public class Pessoa {

    String nome;
    String apelido;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String apelido) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.apelido = apelido;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getApelido() {
        return apelido;
    }

    public void setApelido(String apelido) {
        this.apelido = apelido;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa{" + "nome=" + nome + ", apelido=" + apelido + '}';
    }
}
```

Quando eu rodo a classe `ServidorTCPBasico` tudo OK, mas quando eu rodo a classe `ClienteTCPBasico` da o seguinte erro:

> Erro: Connection reset

Eu usei como exemplo para desenvolver esse codigo  o artigo da [DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/java-sockets-criando-comunicacoes-em-java/9465)
Usei as classes de mesmo nome apenas substitui a classe Date pela classe Pessoa.   Pretendia  passar um objeto criado por mim usando socket , mas infelizmente não deu certo! Onde existe um erro nessa aplicação?

Eu penso que o erro esta em usar a classe `ObjectOutputStream` para ler um tipo não primitivo, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Estou testando aqui (estou baixando o JDK), mas de olhar por cima parece um problema na maneira que esta mandando a escrita pro cliente. O download demora um pouco aqui, mas assim que conseguir eu posto uma resposta ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Puxa cara, muito obrigado pela força, estou tentando ! Fico no aguardo!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  O amigo Leonardo percebeu o meu erro, havia esquecido de implementar a classe seriaalizable. Valeu cara!! Muito obrigado pela consideração!!

Comment: Legal, eu vi, até me ajudou :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente implementar a interface `Serializeble` na sua classe `Pessoa`, quando você implementa essa interface sua classe fica "serializavel".

Comment: Obrigado, exatamente como esqueci de uma coisa dessas,vou tentar aqui!! Valeu

Comment: Beleza, se te ajudou não esqueça de marcar a resposta como certa, e bons estudos :)

Comment: Deu certo, consegui.Muito obrigado cara !!!!!

Comment: Ótimo, parabéns +1

Comment: Valeu pessoal, estou muito feliz de estar contribuindo no stackoverflow.